# comparing the value of each round of a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, random, compare

Is there a way to grab the resulting number from each iteration of this loop and compare it to the next?

This is a Slot Machine Sim in Java,
I'm trying to find a way to see how many of the results match.
so I thought I would capture the number that is resulted from each round of the For loop and compare it to the previous one.

1. but I have no idea how to write that?
2. is there a better way to do this?

what I have so far:

```
      for (int count=1; count<= 3 ; ++count)
      {

         number = slotM.nextInt(6);

         switch (number)
         {
            case 0:
               System.out.print("-cherries-");
               break;
            case 1:
               System.out.print("-Oranges-");
               break;
            case 2:
               System.out.print("-Palms-");
               break;
            case 3:
               System.out.print("-Bells-");
               break;
            case 4:
               System.out.print("-Melones-");
               break;
            default:
               System.out.print("-Bars-");
               break;
         }
         System.out.print(number);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep there are several better ways. If you have a fixed number of options (6 in your case) an `enum` might be a good option:

```
enum Picture {
    CHERRIES, ORANGES, PALMS, BELLS, MELONS, BARS;

    public String getName() {
        return "-" + name().substring(0, 1) + name().substring(1).toLowerCase() + "-";
}
```

That way you can store your numbers as pictures rather than numbers.

```
Picture pictures[3];
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++)
    picture[i] = Picture.values[random.nextInt(pictures.length)];
```

To get the printed version:

```
for (Picture picture: picture) 
    System.out.print(picture.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need some kind of storage outside of the loop so that each iteration can reference it.

`int[] results` Look in to arrays - you can put the results of each round into a part of the array, and look up the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your count variable in the for loop, just declare outside and make a comparison with it